# Python blocksize size confusion

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to python programming, hence my confusion in this section. When I assign a blocksize in my code, say, *blocksize=512*, is it in bytes?

```
        BLOCKSIZE = 65536
        start_time = process_time()
        hasher = hashlib.sha512()

        with open(file_dir+file_name, 'rb') as hashfile:
            buf = hashfile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            while len(buf) > 0:
                hasher.update(buf)
                buf = hashfile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        hashfile.close()
```

Comment: That depends entirely on what is using it. Please show the code you're referring to.

Comment: I'm using to generate a hash checksum by reading sections only at a time. Code is below:

Comment: The argument to `read()` is in bytes.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks!